# NoClassDefFoundError despite multiDex enabled on post 21 SDK

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

My app is targeted with `minSdk` of 21. Recently we pushed an updated to the PlayStore. This update is causing a large number of `noClassDefFoundError` on the `onCreate` function. This is seen on SDK 29 (the latest). I have `multiDex` and `AndroidX` already enabled.

This has left me puzzled. I have gone through other links that suggest updating libraries and the official documentation that suggest removing multiDex support given my minSDK target of 21.

Any suggestions are welcome.

One such stacktrace is as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:242)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:4)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:4)
  at com.myapp.android.ui.myapp.onCreate (myapp.java:15)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7955)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7944)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1307)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3531)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3703)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2216)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Comment: You have added multidex library as a dependency? If not then add the below library in app-level Gradle file:,

implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya: thank you for your response. I had added multidex as a dependency. These errors are after adding it. Now I think i might remove it because the app already has minSDK 21.